# What is the difference between tf.keras.layers.Input() and tf.keras.layers.Flatten()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have seen multiple uses of both `tf.keras.layers.Flatten()` (ex. [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/autoencoder#first_example_basic_autoencoder)) and `tf.keras.layers.Input()` (ex. [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/autoencoder#define_a_convolutional_autoencoder)). After reading the documentation, it is not clear to me

1. whether either of them uses the other
2. whether both can be used interchangeably when introducing to a model an input layer (let's say with dimensions `(64, 64)`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the confusion comes from using a `tf.keras.Sequential` model, which does not need an explicit `Input` layer. Consider the following two models, which are equivalent:

```
import tensorflow as tf

model1 = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='relu'),
    ])

model1.build((1, 28, 28, 1))
```

```
model2 = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Input((28, 28, 1)),
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='relu'),
    ])
```

The difference is that I explicitly set the input shape of `model2` using an `Input` layer. In `model1`, the input shape will be inferred when you pass real data to it or call `model.build`.

Now regarding the `Flatten` layer, this layer simply converts a n-dimensional tensor (for example `(28, 28, 1)`) into a 1D tensor `(28 x 28 x 1)`. The `Flatten` layer and `Input` layer can coexist in a `Sequential` model but do not depend on each other.

Comment: So If I understand correctly, in the example of code I used for the `tf.keras.layers.Input` class, the data are not flattened, they are kept in the same shape, and the class is just used to specify their shape. In that specific example it _is_ necessary to use `Input`, although the model is Sequential, right?

Comment: So If I understand correctly, in the example of code I used for the tf.keras.layers.Input class, the data are not flattened, they are kept in the same shape, and the class is just used to specify their shape <--yes. ,,,,, In that specific example it is necessary to use Input, although the model is Sequential, right? <-- it is optional not necessary.

Comment: Ok this solves my questions! One last thing, could you please tell me 1-2 cases/models where `Input` is necessary?

Comment: The `Input` layer is always necessary when using the `Keras` functional API. Go through the docs here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model?version=nightly